# Apache settings for chunk file upload

Tags: php, apache

I have a bit of a strange situation I am trying to resolve.  I am using [DropzoneJS](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) to perform chunk uploads to my server.  So when working on my local computer, things work great.  Here is an example of the chunks being sent simultaneously
[image: Localhost]

So you can clearly see things work as expected.  When I move it to a live server however (this is not shared hosting but a private VPN), it seems to only upload one chunk at a time.  So it will wait for the first chunk to finish before it starts uploading the second chunk

[image: Live server]

I am not really a server expert, so not sure if there is a certain configuration option I need to enable?  Within my `.htaccess` I am currently setting the following

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value post_max_size 1024M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
    php_value max_execution_time 0
    php_value max_input_time 0
</IfModule>
```

However this obviously isnt enough.  I do see the live server has something called `apache2handler` which has

```
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
```

Not sure if this has anything to do with it?  Really just looking for information as to why it does not do things parallel on the live server?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check the difference in headers of the request between your local server and the prod one, they might hint as to the difference in server configuration.
Why do you use htaccess if yo control the server?

Comment: Will check the headers.  I control the server, but it contains different applications.  I set things up with a default vhost for all applications, and then let the applications make their own settings via the htaccess